# Integer not incrementing as expected

Tags: java, android

Before I asked about the total amount of SIZE and quantity, I also updated my code variable.
But I am sorry that I have encountered new materials and new questions now.....

```
 int pearl1 = 10, Cocount1 = 10, Perilla1 = 10, 
 pudding1 = 10, redbeans1 = 10, aloe1 = 10, jelly1 = 10, jade1 = 10;

     less.setOnClickListener( totalprice );
    plus.setOnClickListener( totalprice );
    Perilla.setOnClickListener( totalprice );
    jelly.setOnClickListener( totalprice );
    pearl.setOnClickListener( totalprice );
    aloe.setOnClickListener( totalprice );
    Coconut.setOnClickListener( totalprice );
    pudding.setOnClickListener( totalprice );
    redbeans.setOnClickListener( totalprice );
    jade.setOnClickListener( totalprice );


}

public OnClickListener totalprice = new
        OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.less: {
                        if (count > 0) {
                            count--;
                            textView.setText( "" + count );
                            if (medium.isChecked()) {
                                total_price.setText( Integer.toString( Integer.parseInt( "45" ) * count ) );
                                counter = Integer.parseInt( total_price.getText().toString() );
                                buttled.setChecked( false );
                            } else if (buttled.isChecked()) {
                                total_price.setText( Integer.toString( Integer.parseInt( "45" ) * count * 0 ) );
                                count = Integer.parseInt( total_price.getText().toString() );
                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText( Main20Activity.this, " 無瓶裝! 請重新選擇!", LENGTH_SHORT );
                                toast.show();
                            } else {
                                total_price.setText( Integer.toString( Integer.parseInt( "80" ) * count ) );
                                counter = Integer.parseInt( total_price.getText().toString() );
                                buttled.setChecked( false );

                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                    case R.id.plus: {
                        if (count < max) {
                            count++;
                            textView.setText( "" + count );
                            if (large.isChecked()) {

                                total_price.setText( Integer.toString( Integer.parseInt( "80" ) * count ) );
                                counter = Integer.parseInt( total_price.getText().toString() );
                                buttled.setChecked( false );
                            } else if (buttled.isChecked()) {
                                total_price.setText( Integer.toString( Integer.parseInt( "45" ) * count * 0 ) );
                                count = Integer.parseInt( total_price.getText().toString() );
                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText( Main20Activity.this, "  無瓶裝! 請重新選擇!", LENGTH_SHORT );
                                toast.show();
                            } else {
                                total_price.setText( Integer.toString( Integer.parseInt( "45" ) * count ) );
                                counter = Integer.parseInt( total_price.getText().toString() );
                                buttled.setChecked( false );
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                }
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.Perilla: {
                        counter = counter + Perilla1;
                        total_price.setText( counter );
                    }
                    case R.id.jelly: {
                        counter = counter + jelly1;
                        total_price.setText( counter );
                    }
                    case R.id.redbeans: {
                        counter = counter + redbeans1;
                        total_price.setText( counter );
                    }
                    case R.id.jade: {
                        counter = counter + jade1;
                        total_price.setText( counter );
                    }
                    case R.id.pearl: {
                        counter = counter + pearl1;
                        total_price.setText( counter );
                    }
                    case R.id.Coconut: {
                        counter = counter + Cocount1;
                        total_price.setText( counter );
                    }
                    case R.id.pudding: {
                        counter = counter + pudding1;
                        total_price.setText( counter );
                    }
                    case R.id.aloe: {
                        counter = counter + aloe1;
                        total_price.setText( counter );
                    }


                }
            }
        };
```

My understanding is:
I replaced total_price with "counter".
After selecting Perilla's ingredients, total_price should be increased by 10 in the output, isn't it?

I use the case and declare the same setOnClickListener
But after I executed it unexpectedly quit

Comment: What is `max` in `if (count < max) {`?

Comment: I have announced max=99 in front.
Indicates a maximum of 99

Comment: Place `Log.e("Plus", " was called");` directly below `case R.id.plus: {` and check your logs to see if the log gets called.

Answer (score 0):

You are only instantiating one variable with the integer 10:

```
int pearl1, Cocount1, Perilla1,
    pudding1, redbeans1, aloe1, 
    jelly1, jade1 = 10;
```

Change to:

```
int pearl1 = 10, Cocount1 = 10, perilla1 = 10, pudding1 = 10, redbeans1 = 10, aloe1 = 10, jelly1 = 10, jade1 = 10;
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought I could announce it together.

Comment: I have done something wrong with the code in the back. Why is my total amount still not changed?

Comment: Try to make your main activity implement OnCheckedChangeListener and do pudding.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this) for all the ingredients then implement a switch on the OnCheckedChangeListener method and response accordingly

Answer (score 0):

There was a few issues with your implementation. The first is that you are placing a `OnClickListener` inside another `OnClickListener`. The second is your `break` statements was incorrect. Please see my implementation below:

```
int pearl1 = 10, Cocount1 = 10, perilla1 = 10, pudding1 = 10, redbeans1 = 10, aloe1 = 10, jelly1 = 10, jade1 = 10;
int max = 99;

private Button.OnClickListener money = new
    OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {   
                case R.id.medium: {
                    total_price.setText("45");
                    counter = Integer.parseInt( total_price.getText().toString() );
                    break;
                } 
                case R.id.large: {
                    total_price.setText("80");
                    counter = Integer.parseInt( total_price.getText().toString() );
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.bottled: {
                    total_price.setText( "" );
                    break;
                }
            }
            less = (ImageButton) findViewById( R.id.less );
            plus = (ImageButton) findViewById( R.id.plus );

            less.setOnClickListener( AddandLess );
            plus.setOnClickListener( AddandLess );

    }
});



private Button.OnClickListener AddandLess = new 
    OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.less: {
                    if (count > 0) {
                        count--;
                        textView.setText( "" + count );
                    }
                    break;
                }

                case R.id.plus: {
                    if (count < max) {
                        count++;
                        textView.setText( "" + count );
                    }
                    break; 
                }

        }
    }        
});


Perilla.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean c){
    if (c) {
        counter=counter+Perilla1;
        total_price.setText(counter);
    }
  }
});


jelly.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean c)
        if (c) {
            counter=counter+jelly1;
            total_price.setText(counter);
            }  
});

aloe.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean c) {
        if (c) {
            counter=counter+aloe1;
            total_price.setText(counter);
        }
    }  
});

redbeans.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean c) {
            if (c) {
                counter=counter+redbeans1;
                total_price.setText(counter);
            }                                
        }

});

pearl.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean c) {
        if (c) {
            counter=counter+pearl1;
            total_price.setText(counter);

        }
    }
});

Coconut.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean c) {
        if (c) {
            counter=counter+Cocount1;
            total_price.setText(counter);
        }
    }
});

jade.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean c) {
        if (c) {
            counter=counter+jade1;
            total_price.setText(counter);
        }
    }
});

pudding.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean c) {
        if (c) {
            counter=counter+pudding1;
            total_price.setText(counter);
        }
    }
});

int TotalPrice = counter * count;
String strTotalPrice = String.valueOf( TotalPrice );
total_price.setText( strTotalPrice );
```

Edit:

The error mentioned in the comments is because `textView` is not initialize by the time it gets called. Add the following in `onCreate`:

```
textView = findViewById(R.id.nameOfTextView);
```

Comment: If I have used setOnCheckedChangeListener before, can I continue to use it later?

Comment: Use it to judge that you cannot select SIZE repeatedly.

Comment: If you are still in the same Activity then yes you can.

Comment: What if I have a lot of code in between, because I found that I will leave android directly after execution.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{hk.csim.dm/hk.csim.dm.Main20Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I just can't execute it by pressing Perilla.

Comment: Look at my answer, I tested it before you changed the question. You have `if(Perilla.isChecked())`, this is unnecessary, it can be replaced with `if(isChecked)`.

Comment: You also did not change your integers to `int pearl1 = 10, Cocount1 = 10, Perilla1 = 10, pudding1 = 10, redbeans1 = 10, aloe1 = 10, jelly1 = 10, jade1 = 10;`

Comment: I will fail after clicking Perilla after execution.

Comment: 8-06 06:33:02.501 10222-10222/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10058: Read-only file system
08-06 06:33:07.127 10222-10222/hk.csim.dm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: hk.csim.dm, PID: 10222
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5a